# Assign default program to scanner button

Tags: windows-7, scanner

When I press the start button on my Epson V500 Photo scanner, I am confronted with 4 choices of which I always need the same one. How can I make the start button on my scanner automaticaly start the same application without user intervention? I am using win7 home 64bit.

Comment: Dunno. Read the documentation that came with the scanner.

Comment: someone's voted to close this as 'too localized'.  i disagree -- asking how to configure one's hardware or software is what Super User is here for.  the answer to this question probably fits many models of Epson scanners, and i don't see any other possible interpretation of 'too localized' that applies.

Comment: This is for many (or perhaps all) types of scanner, not just Epson. I had this question for an HP scanner.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally found the solution:

Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers\Epsone Perfection V500

Right click => Scan Properties

Tab Events

'Prompt which program to run' is selected

Select 'Start with this program' => done.

The issue was -imho- not too localized as it applies to many devices with events. It is not a *Epson* problem to my opinion, but a general customization in Windows, which I failed to discover up until now.

Looks like a simple solution which could be googled in no time, but I have tried back and forth to find it before posting the Q. The fact that it could not be done with standard win7 settings just bugged me to the bone, so I guess I went the extra mile.

Thx everybody for thinking along.

Answer (score 1):

Use automation scripting programs such as [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml) or [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)

What you would want to do is write your own script running in the background to trigger an action when WINDOW NAME "Epson V500 Photo scanner start button program" is in focus or exists. Let the loop cycle every 1-5 seconds depending how fast you want the script to trigger.

After you press the start button, I assume that a program is automatically launched (lets call it "Epson V500 Photo scanner start button program").

Once the automation scripting program detects that the window "Epson V500 Photo scanner start button program" is in focus or exists, you can do something like:

1) Bring "Epson V500 Photo scanner start button program" to front. (In case it's buried beneath a bunch of windows and to make sure it's the window in focus)

2.a) MouseClick X,Y (to automatically click the choice that you usually manually click.)

OR

2.b) SendKey("Alt+1") (If there is a shortcut key, it's better to use that instead of messing around with mouse clicking and screen coordinates, since the window might get moved from its default position)